# HiddenFor not passing value to controller?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I need to obtain an Id from model to the controller for each value placed in table row. However, when inspect the results AmbassadorEventId = 0.

I tried clarifying with `@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Staffings[i].AmbassadorEventId)` instead of `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Staffings[i].AmbassadorEventId)`

View:

```
<form asp-action="StaffStudents" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">
                    <table id="staffingTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Event</th>
                                <th>Sub Event</th>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Academic Area</th>
                                <th>Majors</th>
                                <th>Minors</th>
                                <th>Staff?</th>  
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Staffings.Count; i++)
                            { 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Model.Staffings[i].Event.EventName</td>
                                    <td>@Model.Staffings[i].SubEvent.SubEventName</td>
                                    <td>@Model.Staffings[i].FirstName @Model.Staffings[i].LastName</td>
                                    <td>@Model.Staffings[i].AcademicArea</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Staffings[i].Majors)
                                        {
                                            item.ToString();
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Staffings[i].Minors)
                                        {
                                            item.ToString();
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Staffings[i].Staff)</td>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Staffings[i].ProfileId)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Staffings[i].AmbassadorEventId)
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" id="addStaffingsBtn" class="wdn-button wdn-button-complement" style="float:right;">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

Model:

```
public class AdminStaffStudentViewModel
    {   
        public List<Staffing> Staffings { get; set; } = new List<Staffing>();
    }


    public class Staffing
    {

        public Entity.SubEvent SubEvent { get; set; }

        public Event Event { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string AcademicArea { get; set; }

        public List<string> Majors { get; set; }

        public List<string> Minors { get; set; }

        public string ClassLevel { get; set; }

        public List<AcademicYear> AcademicHistory { get; set; }

        public bool Staff { get; set; }
        public int ProfileId { get; internal set; }
        public int AmbassadorEventId { get; internal set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public IActionResult StaffStudents(AdminStaffStudentViewModel model)
        {

                _adminManager.StaffStudentsToEvents(model.Staffings);


            return RedirectToAction(nameof(StaffStudents));
        }
```

I should be able to return the value from my view to the controller on post.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figured it out, I had my setters qualified as internal for those values I needed.